# How to select "best" (Max) value by day for each category? In MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, max

I'm using MS SQL and am trying to find the "best" (Max sales volume) day for customer reps. I currently have a table with the columns:

`RepName, Date, Volume`

That has the following data

```
 - Joe Salesman,    01/01/2021, 2
 - Mike Moneymaker, 01/01/2021, 14
 - Rachel Revenue, 01/01/2021, 7
 - Joe Salesman,    01/02/2021, 9
 - Mike Moneymaker, 01/02/2021, 8
 - Rachel Revenue, 01/02/2021, 12
 - Joe Salesman,    01/03/2021, 7
 - Mike Moneymaker, 01/03/2021, 11
 - Rachel Revenue, 01/03/2021, 14
```

with this continuing up to today's data.

I'm trying to list the Max Volume per Rep, and the respective date the rep obtained that volume. This would look like:

```
- Joe Salesman, 01/02/2021, 9  
- Mike Moneymaker, 01/01/2021, 14
- Rachel Revenue, 01/03/2021, 14
```

Current Code I'm using is more or less in this format:

```
SELECT RepName, Date, MAX(Volume)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY RepName, Date
```

However, this is returning all rows of data in MyTable, instead of showing the maximums.

Anybody have any insight or tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RepName ORDER BY Volume DESC) as seqnum
      FROM MyTable t
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```